# PHP Generating "Ghost" sessions in the sessions table

Tags: php, mysql

- Windows Version: Win 8 64bit
- WAMP Version: 2.5 64Bit
- PHP Version: 5.5.12

PHP is generating what I'd have to describe as "ghost" sessions in the sessions table, for every page request. The weirdest part is that just clicking on the browser window seems to be enough to create a new session. It happens in Firefox and Chrome (never installed any extensions/addons in Chrome) but doesn't happen in IE11.

At this point I've no idea if it's a bug/glitch in the way that Firefox and Chrome handle cookies or it it's a bug with PHP. The code I'm testing with is below (including the SHOW CREATE TABLE for the test table).

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT | E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_WARNING | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_USER_NOTICE | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR);

$db_type = 'mysql';
$db_host = 'local_host';

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost';
$user = 'sess_test_user';
$password = 'password';

try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
// Create a new instance of PDO (connect to the database)
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Failed To Connect To Database');
}

class db_session_handler implements SessionHandlerInterface {

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;

    }

    public function open($save_path,$session_name) {
        $this->db;
        return true;
    }

    public function close() {
        unset($this->db);
        return true;
    }

    public function read($session_id) {

        try {
            $sql="
                SELECT
                    sess_data
                FROM
                    session_table
                WHERE
                    sess_id = :sess_id
            ";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':sess_id', $session_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if (count($res) <> 1 ) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return $res[0]['sess_data'];
            }
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function write($session_id,$session_data) {      
        try {
            $sql="
                SELECT
                    sess_data
                FROM
                    session_table
                WHERE
                    sess_id = :sess_id
            ";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':sess_id', $session_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            if (count($res) === 0) {
                $sql="
                INSERT INTO
                    session_table
                (
                      sess_id
                    , user
                    , start
                    , last_activity
                    , expires
                    , sess_data
                )
                VALUES
                    (
                          :sess_id
                        , '0'
                        , NOW()
                        , NOW()
                        , DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
                        , :sess_data                        
                    )               
                ";
                $stmt->bindParam(':sess_id', $session_id);
                $stmt->bindParam(':sess_data', $session_data);
            } else {
                $sql="
                    UPDATE
                        session_table
                    SET
                          last_activity = NOW()
                        , expires = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
                        , sess_data = :sess_data
                    WHERE
                        sess_id = :sess_id              
                ";
            }
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':sess_id', $session_id);
            $stmt->bindParam(':sess_data', $session_data);
            $stmt->execute();
            return true;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function destroy($session_id) {
        try {
            $sql="
                DELETE FROM
                    session_table
                WHERE
                    sess_id = :sess_id
            ";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':sess_id', $session_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            return true;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function gc($max_lifetime) {
        try {
            $sql="
                DELETE FROM
                    session_table
                WHERE
                    last_activity < expires
            ";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        session_write_close();
    }
}

$db_session_handler = new db_session_handler($db);
session_set_save_handler($db_session_handler,true);
session_start();

echo session_id();

echo "
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `session_table` (
  `sess_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_activity` datetime NOT NULL,
  `expires` datetime NOT NULL,
  `sess_data` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sess_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
";      
?>
```

Comment: 99% of the time this is the result of your session cookie not being accepted.

Comment: Just emptied the sessions table (after computer was switched on), Fired up the test script, firebug showed a cookie as having been sent, the test script, didn't echo any cookie. Two entries had been created in the session table, one with the session id that was in the cookie sent.  Refreshed the test script and it echoed the session id from the cookie but yet another entry had been created in the session table

Comment: Commented out the use of the database session handler and opened up the folder where wamp stores sessions. It seems like it's possibly something to do with PHPMyAdmin as that seems to generate a new session for every page request. I use PHPMyAdmin for interacting with mysql. I'm wondering if there might be a bug in PHPMyAdmin and when I store sessions in the database, possibly something is conflicting somewhere

Comment: Just added some regenerating of session IDs to the test script: session_start();
echo '<pre>';
echo session_id();
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
session_regenerate_id(true);
echo session_id();
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
session_regenerate_id(true);
$_SESSION['user'] = 'test_user';
echo session_id();
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
session_regenerate_id(true);
echo session_id();
echo '</pre>';

Comment: In the session table that gives  sess_id  user  start  last_activity  expires  sess_data
7t6cn09b5h3ie3g1kboeu0b162  0  2015-10-03 19:23:39  2015-10-03 19:23:39  2015-10-03 19:53:39  user|s:9:"test_user";
pt1m5qhem8gj8bmad5043o5bm7  0  2015-10-03 19:23:40  2015-10-03 19:23:40  2015-10-03 19:53:40  user|s:9:"test_user";

Comment: Firebug registers each of the cookies as having been set with the last one regsistered by firebug as being the current one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like FireFox and Chrome were the culprits, after completely uninstalling them then reinstalling them the problem has gone away so probably something in each has gotten corrupted at some point

Comment: Update: Neither resetting nor re-installing have worked. Tried on a Windows 7 computer and no problems, at this point I'm wondering if Windows 8 has a glitch with the way it deals with session cookies

Comment: If anyone else gets something similar happen try running chrome and Firefox as an administrator and in compatibility mode for windows 7, that (fingers crossed) seems to have cured the problem, so possibly behind the scenes there must have been some sort of permissions issue, possibly something is handled differently between windows 7 and windows 8